# Is CONVERT non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, non-deterministic, sql-convert

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyStats
(
Date date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAV int NOT NULL,
SP500 decimal(8,4) NULL,
R2K decimal(8,4) NULL,
NetExp decimal(8,4) NULL,
GrossExp decimal(8,4) NULL,
[YrMn]  AS (CONVERT([varchar](7),[Date])),
)
GO
```

I was thinking that I may need to build an indexed view on this at some point so I wanted to make sure my calculated column [YrMn] was deterministic. I ran this check:

```
Select COLUMNPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID('Portfolio.DailyStats'),'YrMn', 'IsDeterministic')
```

This returned a value of 0 indicating that the column is non-deterministic. I am struggling to figure out why this is the case given that the column value will always the same for a specific date. Does it have to do with the convert function and what is it?

Comment: You need to give it a style parameter to make it deterministic.

Comment: You need to add a `style` to the convert for it to be deterministic: `CONVERT(varchar(7),[date],103)` for instance

Comment: Slight detour...not sure that a date datatype makes for a good primary key. And to be honest the YrMn column could easily be handled in the front end with formatting of the already existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes deterministic if you include the third parameter for `convert()`, the `style`. e.g.

```
[YrMn]  AS (convert([varchar](7),[Date],120))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DFNA25042